Can't mock camera controller for unit tests
By online examples I've wrote CameraBloc implementation:
class CameraUtils {
  Future<List<CameraDescription>> getAvailableCameras() async => await availableCameras();

  Future<CameraDescription> findBestCamera(CameraLensDirection cameraLensDirection) async {
    final cameras = await getAvailableCameras();
    return cameras.firstWhere((camera) => camera.lensDirection == cameraLensDirection);
  }

  Future<CameraController> createCameraController(CameraDescription camera, ResolutionPreset preset) async {
    return CameraController(camera, preset, enableAudio: false);
  }

  Future<bool> requestPermission() async {
    return await Permission.camera.request().isGranted;
  }
}

sealed class CameraState extends Equatable {
  const CameraState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class CameraInitial extends CameraState {}

final class CameraReady extends CameraState {
  final CameraController cameraController;

  const CameraReady({required this.cameraController});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [cameraController];
}

final class CameraFailure extends CameraState {
  final String error;

  const CameraFailure({this.error = "CameraFailure"});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [error];
}

final class CameraPermissionDenied extends CameraState {}

sealed class CameraEvent {}

final class CameraStopped extends CameraEvent {}

final class CameraInitialized extends CameraEvent {}

class CameraBloc extends Bloc<CameraEvent, CameraState> {
  final CameraUtils cameraUtils;
  final ResolutionPreset resolutionPreset;
  final CameraLensDirection cameraLensDirection;

  CameraController? _controller;

  CameraBloc({
    required this.cameraUtils,
    this.resolutionPreset = ResolutionPreset.high,
    this.cameraLensDirection = CameraLensDirection.back,
  }) : super(CameraInitial()) {
    on<CameraInitialized>(_onCameraInitialized);
    on<CameraStopped>(_onCameraStopped);
  }

  Future _onCameraInitialized(
      CameraInitialized event, Emitter<CameraState> emit) async {
    try {
      final isGranted = await cameraUtils.requestPermission();

      if (!isGranted) {
        emit(CameraPermissionDenied());
        return;
      }

      final camera = await cameraUtils.findBestCamera(cameraLensDirection);
      _controller =
      await cameraUtils.createCameraController(camera, resolutionPreset);
      await _controller!.initialize();
      emit(CameraReady(cameraController: _controller!));
    } on CameraException catch (error) {
      _controller?.dispose();
      emit(CameraFailure(error: error.description ?? error.toString()));
    } catch (error) {
      emit(CameraFailure(error: error.toString()));
    }
  }

  Future _onCameraStopped(
      CameraStopped event, Emitter<CameraState> emit) async {
    _controller?.dispose();
    emit(CameraInitial());
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    return super.close();
  }
}

There is a nothing special... However, I faced troubles with mocking in unit tests:
final class MockCameraDescription extends Mock implements CameraDescription {}
final class MockCameraController extends Mock implements CameraController {}
final class MockCameraUtils extends Mock implements CameraUtils {}

void main() {
  late MockCameraDescription camera;
  late MockCameraController cameraController;
  late MockCameraUtils cameraUtils;

  setUp(() {
    camera = MockCameraDescription();
    cameraController = MockCameraController();
    cameraUtils = MockCameraUtils();

    // Default responses
    when(cameraController.initialize()).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value());
    when(cameraUtils.createCameraController(camera, ResolutionPreset.max)).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(cameraController));
  });

  group('CameraInitialized', () {
    blocTest<CameraBloc, CameraState>(
      'Should initialize the camera controller',
      build: () => CameraBloc(cameraUtils: cameraUtils),
      act: (CameraBloc bloc) => bloc.add(CameraInitialized()),
      expect: () => [CameraReady(cameraController: cameraController)],
    );

    blocTest<CameraBloc, CameraState>(
      'Should return a permission denied state',
      build: () {
        when(cameraController.initialize()).thenAnswer((_) => Future.error(
            CameraException("cameraPermission",
                "MediaRecorderCamera permission not granted")));
        return CameraBloc(cameraUtils: cameraUtils);
      },
      act: (CameraBloc bloc) => bloc.add(CameraInitialized()),
      expect: () => [CameraPermissionDenied()],
    );

    blocTest<CameraBloc, CameraState>(
      'Should throw an error (no camera on device)',
      build: () {
        when(cameraUtils.createCameraController(camera, ResolutionPreset.max)).thenAnswer((_) => Future.error(Exception("Bad state: no element")));
        return CameraBloc(cameraUtils: cameraUtils);
      },
      act: (CameraBloc bloc) => bloc.add(CameraInitialized()),
      expect: () => [const CameraFailure(error: "Exception: Bad state: no element")],
    );
  });

  group('CameraStopped', () {
    blocTest<CameraBloc, CameraState>(
      'Should dispose the camera',
      build: () => CameraBloc(cameraUtils: cameraUtils),
      act: (CameraBloc bloc) =>
      bloc..add(CameraInitialized())..add(CameraStopped()),
      expect: () => [
        CameraReady(cameraController: cameraController),
        CameraInitial(),
      ],
    );
  });
}

When I try to launch tests they fail with errors:
test/domain/camera_test.dart 9:13   MockCameraController.initialize
test/domain/camera_test.dart 23:27  main.<fn>

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<void>'

package:mockito/src/mock.dart 1207:5  when
test/domain/camera_test.dart 23:5     main.<fn>

Bad state: Cannot call `when` within a stub response

package:mockito/src/mock.dart 1207:5  when
test/domain/camera_test.dart 23:5     main.<fn>

Bad state: Cannot call `when` within a stub response

package:mockito/src/mock.dart 1207:5  when
test/domain/camera_test.dart 23:5     main.<fn>

Bad state: Cannot call `when` within a stub response

I am a beginner in flutter_test and mockito and can't get why. Seems I did the same steps as in their official examples...

when(cameraController.initialize()).thenAnswer((_) => Future<void>.value()); doesn't work as well.

After switching to build_runner with @GenerateMocks([   CameraDescription,   CameraController,   CameraUtils, ]) it started to work.
